# JBAS010447: Connection is not valid

Tags: oracle, database-connection, datasource, jboss6.x, service-name

I need help, when i try to create a datasource connection on jboss show this error **JBAS010447: Connection is not valid**

my connection url is **jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL**

on my jboss log show **ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be either translated to English or posted on https://es.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: question translated into english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JDBC driver and Oracle Database version are not suitable. Please check your ojdbc.jar [Check this link](https://medium.com/@madeeshafernando/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-exception-acd8eaf1ff3c)